# How to correct the error of this program

Tags: ios

I have a code but in this code there is an error and I don't know Why i has this error.
I put this code because i want my ball hit least the border soy the screens.
You can see my code :

```
CGPoint ballCenter = ball.center;
CGRect ballRect = CGRectMake(50, 73, 50, 50); // an arbitrary location for the ball, you would normally use the frame property of the ball here
CGRect s = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
CGRect adjustedScreenRect = CGRectMake(s.x-50   // take the ball's (width or height) and divide it by two to get the distance to the center. Then multiply it by two and subtract from the appropriate dimension(x offset (width), y offset (height), width (width), height (height)). 
BOOL isOnScreen = CGRectContainsPoint(adjutedScreenRect, ballCenter);
// do whatever with the BOOL from the above line...
```

I have an error at this line:

```
CGRect adjustedScreenRect = CGRectMake(s.x-50   // take the ball's (width or height) and divide it by two to get the distance to the center. Then multiply it by two and subtract from the appropriate dimension(x offset (width), y offset (height), width (width), height (height)). 
BOOL isOnScreen = CGRectContainsPoint(adjutedScreenRect, ballCenter);
```

And the error is "no member named "x" in struct CGRect".

thanks you for your help

The answer is `CGRect adjustedScreenRect = CGRectMake(s.origin.x-50

BOOL isOnScreen = CGRectContainsPoint(adjutedScreenRect, ballCenter);`

But I have an error Expected ) on BOOL .

Can you help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean `s.origin.x`, not `s.x`.  Because CGRect is a struct of a CGPoint and a CGSize, directly accessing the x value of a CGRect is not possible without specifying which part of the struct you want to access first.

Edit:

You never actually closed the parenthesis, or satisfied all 4 arguments, of the CGRect.  Try this:

```
CGRectMake(s.origin.x-50, s.origin.y, width,height);
```

Comment: yeah, just what I was about to say.

Comment: Edit your post with the offending line of code, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: CodaFi , I Edited my post with your answer

Comment: Hello, I have an error with "width " use of undeclared identifier "width" Can you help me , i'm very sorry if I deranged you .

Comment: Replace width and height with any numbers you want.